# Why does my array -count method return zero after adding an element?

Tags: objective-c

I have class like the following

```
@interface Node : NSObject {

NSString* description;
NSString* ae;
NSString* ip;
NSString*  port;
}

@property ( nonatomic , retain ) NSString* description;
@property ( nonatomic , retain ) NSString* ae;
@property ( nonatomic , retain ) NSString* ip;
@property ( nonatomic , retain ) NSString* port;

@end

#import "Node.h"

@implementation Node

@synthesize description,ae,ip,port;

@end
```

I want to create nsmutablearray of it So I do the following

```
NSMutableArray* nodesArray ;
nodesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Node * insertedNode =[[Node alloc]init] ;
insertedNode.description =@"test";
insertedNode.ae =@"test" ;
insertedNode.ip =@"test";
insertedNode.port =@"test";

[nodesArray addObject: insertedNode] ;

[insertedNode release];
```

then I print the count using

```
NSLog(@"%d",[nodesArray count] ) ;
```

but it always always return 0

any suggestion to solve that

Best regards

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  Please fix your title to describe the actual problem you're actually having.

Comment: @S.Lott I couldn't stand it any longer. Fixed.

Comment: @Abizern: That doesn't help @AMH learn how to write a good question, does it?

Comment: my problem is that I want to create nsmutablearray of class object but no insertion done

Comment: Maybe gentle nudging with examples might work. I fixed his formatting, but I'm not going to fix his code. :)

Comment: where are you trying to `addObjects` to your array? I mean, is it main, a class function, what?

Comment: @AMH: it's the gold standard to start ivars with a lowercase letter.  Fixed.

Comment: @AMH: Change the NSLog to `NSLog(@"%@", nodesArray)` and tell us what you get.

Comment: where are you actually calling `NSLog`? Right after you add the object or in some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `NodesArray` is failing to initialize? You could try testing to see if it is `nil` after you initialize it. (at `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`)

Adding an object to a nil `NSMutableArray *` would fail silently, and `[nil count]` will always return zero.

(No idea why it would fail to initialize, but I can't imagine anything else causing the behavior you're describing.)